# Firebase validate rule. How to make the rules work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Data in Firebase has the following structure:

```
emailsLending
|___-LqQFYK-iI8a8qe2msVk
    |___email
    |___serverTimestamp
```

I wrote the following rules checking the entry in the email field:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "emailsLending": {
      "$emailsLending_id": {
        ".indexOn": "email",
        "email": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i)"   
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I write data to the email field using the Cloud Function, the rule does not apply and I can write anything, for example, "123".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions run with administrative privileges, and by default bypass the security rules of your database.

The logic here is that rules are to protect against malicious behavior from untrusted users, while Cloud Functions are authored by the most trusted users: collaborators on your app. To catch mistakes made by these types of users, you'd typically use unit tests instead of security rules.

If you have a case where this logic doesn't apply and you're using the Realtime Database, you can set `databaseAuthVariableOverride` to the UID of the user to run the code as. For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation on [accessing user authentication information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#accessing_user_authentication_information).